# Android Emulator: Sending and receiving SMS fails (SmsRetreiver, API 22 error)

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I wanted to send SMS messages to my Emulator and receive them with my broadcastreceiver:

```
SmsRetrieverClient smsRetrieverClient = SmsRetriever.getClient(activity);
        smsRetrieverClient
            .startSmsUserConsent(null)
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                // Handle client failure
            });
```

But I get the log:
`Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe`

Also after some time the smsRetreiverClient receives an exception in the failureListener:

`com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 22: API failed to connect while resuming due to an unknown error.`

I don't seem to be able to find a solution for this, maybe someone faced the same issue. An interesting detail: Sending myself SMS messages and receiving them was working on the emulator before, I am not sure why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please clarify --  you said that you used to be able to send yourself SMS from the emulator, but I don't see how that's possible. The emulator doesn't have an active SIM, so it wouldn't be possible for it to make calls, or send SMS

Comment: Wiping the emulator helped, but it would still be interesting to know the reason.

Comment: @user496854 you can do so in the options of the emulator and navigating to the menu "phone" and then send sms to the emulator